# Club overlapping time slots together in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a table which has records of overlapping time-slots.

E.g.: Calendar(Id int, StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime, EventTitle nvarchar(100), ...)

The records would be like

> 1. 01/20/2011 08:15 AM   ---   01/20/2011 08:40 AM
> 2. 01/20/2011 08:20 AM   ---   01/20/2011 08:55 AM
> 3. 01/20/2011 12:30 PM   ---   01/20/2011 01:15 PM
> 4. 01/20/2011 02:00 PM   ---   01/20/2011 02:45 PM
> 5. 01/20/2011 02:15 PM   ---   01/20/2011 02:30 PM
> 6. 01/21/2011 12:30 PM   ---   01/21/2011 01:15 PM
> 7. .......
> 8. .......

The table represents the event schedule of a person

I want to club the overlapping slots together to give:

> 1. 01/20/2011 08:15 AM  ---   01/20/2011 08:55 AM
> 2. 01/20/2011 12:30 PM  ---   01/20/2011 01:15 PM
> 3. 01/20/2011 02:00 PM  ---   01/20/2011 02:45 PM
> 4. 01/21/2011 12:30 PM  ---   01/21/2011 01:15 PM
> 5. ...
> 6. ...

I am stuck at this part of the problem... (I removed my code that I pasted here, as it looks mangled. I am using stackoverflow for the first time.)

Part of my actual requirement is to find a time slot [t] (let's say 25 minutes) between two given dates, which I can accommodate into the schedule. [t] has to be found between 8:00 AM and 05:00 PM on any day.

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781895/checking-for-time-range-overlap-the-watchman-problem-sql

Comment: Tried that solution @danihp. That solution has the assumption that there would be a maximum of two consecutive overlapping time slots.

Applied that to my problem, it fails in one of the cases where there are 3 consecutive overlapping slots.

Comment: Do you need a query or is valid for you a store procedure or function.? What means 25' time slot? Can you explain this last point?

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question.

For a **given date**, lets consider the overlaps (I entered all my date times as per yours but for the 1/1/2011):

```
SELECT        dt1.StartTime AS StartOverlap,
              CASE 
                WHEN dt1.EndTime > dt2.EndTime THEN dt1.EndTime
                ELSE dt2.EndTime
              END AS EndOverlap
FROM          datetimetest dt1, datetimetest dt2
WHERE         dt2.StartTime > dt1.StartTime
AND           dt2.StartTime < dt1.EndTime
```

This gives me:

```
StartOverlap        EndOverlap
01/01/2011 08:15:00 01/01/2011 08:55:00
01/01/2011 14:00:00 01/01/2011 14:45:00
```

Great, we now know the start and end times we can't use that overlap.

How do we get the other none overlapping times?

I would look at all the time periods that are in the overlapping ranges, and then select out the id's that are not in that date range:

```
SELECT id 
FROM (SELECT        dt1.StartTime AS StartOverlap,
                CASE 
                  WHEN dt1.EndTime > dt2.EndTime THEN dt1.EndTime
                  ELSE dt2.EndTime
                END AS EndOverlap
  FROM          datetimetest dt1, datetimetest dt2
  WHERE dt2.StartTime > dt1.StartTime
  AND dt2.StartTime < dt1.EndTime
 ) AS Overlaps, datetimetest dtt

WHERE dtt.StartTime >= Overlaps.StartOverlap 
AND dtt.EndTime <= Overlaps.EndOverlap
```

This gives me a list of all the ids that are in the overlaps. I then just select all of the entries that are NOT in the overlaps:

```
SELECT StartTime, EndTime FROM datetimetest
WHERE id NOT IN(
SELECT id 
FROM (SELECT        dt1.StartTime AS StartOverlap,
                CASE 
                  WHEN dt1.EndTime > dt2.EndTime THEN dt1.EndTime
                  ELSE dt2.EndTime
                END AS EndOverlap
  FROM          datetimetest dt1, datetimetest dt2
  WHERE dt2.StartTime > dt1.StartTime
  AND dt2.StartTime < dt1.EndTime
 ) AS Overlaps, datetimetest dtt

WHERE dtt.StartTime >= Overlaps.StartOverlap 
AND dtt.EndTime <= Overlaps.EndOverlap)
```

To give me:

```
StartTime           EndTime
01/01/2011 12:30:00 01/01/2011 13:15:00
```

I can then union both queries together to give me a list of all used time slots.

As we are effectively cross joining the same table, I would add an additional clause to each query to constrain the date to a single date.

Comment: the solution works for one overlapping period like i have time periods for 8:15 - 8:30 , 8:25-8:40 , 8:20 - 8:50 the solution would fail..